# Bulk Insert multiple documents into SQL server 2016

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I am trying to bulk insert multiple documents(more than 50,000) from the folder. I have this program works but it is time consuming. Please suggest any alternative ways.

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles("C:\\TEST\\", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
using (SqlConnection con= new SqlConnection (conString))
{
    con.Open();
     foreach (string docPath in files)
            {
                   byte[] file;    
                    using (var stream = new FileStream(docPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                    {
                        using (var reader1 = new BinaryReader(stream))
                        {
                            file = reader1.ReadBytes((int)stream.Length);
                        }
                    }

        string insertSQLString = "INSERT INTO dbo.Test(content, path) VALUES(@File, @path)";
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand (insertSQLString, con))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@File", SqlDbType.VarBinary, file.Length).Value = file;                             
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@path", SqlDbType.Text).Value = docPath;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a couple of optimizations.  There's no need to copy the file contents to a byte array before sending to SQL.  You can pass a Stream directly. See [SqlClient Streaming Support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sqlclient-streaming-support).  And if the files are small, you'll want to batch a few together in a commit.  Also it's unnecessary to recreate the SqlCommand each time.

```
        static void Run()
        { 
            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles("C:\\TEST\\", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("server=localhost;database=testdb;integrated security=true"))
            {
                con.Open();
                string insertSQLString = "INSERT INTO dbo.Test(content, path) VALUES(@File, @path)";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(insertSQLString, con);
                var pFile = cmd.Parameters.Add("@File", SqlDbType.VarBinary, -1);
                var pPath = cmd.Parameters.Add("@path", SqlDbType.Text);

                var tran = con.BeginTransaction();
                var fn = 0;
                foreach (string docPath in files)
                {
                    fn += 1;
                    using (var stream = new FileStream(docPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                    {
                        pFile.Value = stream;
                        pPath.Value = docPath;
                        cmd.Transaction = tran;
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        if (fn%10==0)
                        {
                            tran.Commit();
                            tran = con.BeginTransaction();
                            Console.Write("|");
                        }
                        Console.Write(".");
                    }
                }
                tran.Commit();
            }
        }
```

Another approach is to create a [File Table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/blob/filetables-sql-server) and then just robocopy  the files.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `SqlBulkCopy` class from `System.Data.SqlClient` for that. It is very efficient when inserting large bodies of data.

Here you can find an example how that can be done: [http://codinghelmet.com/?path=howto/bulk-insert](http://codinghelmet.com/?path=howto/bulk-insert#custom-solution-for-bulk-insert)

Comment: thanks. I just checked the link. It looks like the data is loaded into an object before bulkcopy. How does it work with documents? Please suggest.

Comment: `SqlBulkCopy` is reading data from the `DataTable`, which means that you have to load all files into memory and populate the `DataTable` first. That is not an expensive operation, though. Files would have to be loaded anyway. The most important aspect of using `SqlBulkCopy` is that it makes one round-trip to the database and everything else happens there. My experience shows that it is the most efficient method of them all.